# Correct R^2 values in linear regression models with full set of factors and no constant in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I have a dataset from an experiment with four treatments, which are coded using four dummy variables which I will call Tr1, Tr2, Tr3 and Tr4. (So to be clear: `Tr1 + Tr2 + Tr3 + Tr4 = 1` for all observations in my dataset.) Now I am estimating a linear regression model where I regress my outcome variable y on all four dummies plus some other regressors, omitting the constant:

```
lm(y ~ Tr1 + Tr2 + Tr3 + Tr4 + var1 + var2 + 0, data = df)
```

The problem is that this model without a constant yields inflated R^2 values. Apparently, Stata has a `, hasconst` option that yields correct R^2 values while accounting for the fact the model is estimated without constant, but that a constant is included in the form of all dummies. Is there something similar in R? Or can somebody please tell me how to calculate R^2 for this model?

Comment: If you drop one of the dummies but include a constant, the model estimated will be the same (modulo adding the constant to your dummies) and the R2 will be correct.

Comment: That's true - so what you are saying is I could simply use the R2 from the equivalent model with constant for my model without constant?

Comment: Yes, @dash2 is correct. FWIW, there is some controversy over what "correct" means in this case. R has a FAQ on this: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-summary_0028_0029-report-strange-results-for-the-R_005e2-estimate-when-I-fit-a-linear-model-with-no-intercept_003f

Comment: I've now gone for the solution proposed by @dash2 and have clarified what I did in the description of the regression. Seems like a good solution to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop one of the dummies but include a constant, the model estimated will be the same (modulo adding the constant to your dummies) and the R2 will be correct:

```r
m <- lm(y ~ Tr2 + Tr3 + Tr4 + var1 + var2, data = df)
rsq <- summary(m)$r.squared
```